# CSS style wont load

Tags: css

I'm working on a WP template. The style.css file loads successfully. But the styling is not applied to many of the elements. You can see it in http://madihaa.mv/v1/
Take a look at child `<p>` in `<div class="home-second-row">`.
In line 758 of style.css file the following can be found

```
.home-second-row p {
width: 225px;
height: 215px;
background: rgb(112, 184, 0);
border-radius: 8px;
margin-right: 10px;
text-align: left;
padding: 20px;
float: left;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 1.3em;
line-height: 1.6em;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

But it is not applied to it.

Comment: Post the **HTML** hierarchy of `.home-second-row p {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with your CSS file. Look at line 742, you haven't closed the declaration with `}`. This is stopping the other declarations afterwards from working.

**EDIT**

Your CSS currently:

```
.navigation-main .menu-item .sub-menu li{
    padding: 5px 10px;
/* site-main */
.site-main{
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

^ That is the issue

Comment: thanks. I spent two hours on this and it turned out to be a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I've used http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator (for http://madihaa.mv/v1/wp-content/themes/madihaastyle/style.css?ver=3.5.1 ) to validate your CSS and there are a few errors with the comments, also found the unclosed decleration already mentioned.

Hope this helps

Comment: Tried the validation myself but it wasn't working for me (bad internet or something) though good idea as there may have been other errors in it like you found.

Comment: That's strange, I also had problems with the connection. I had to paste the entire doc to get it to work instead of using the URL